# IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0 CE

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

TASK [addon : Waiting for cloudant to start] ***************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (50 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (49 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (48 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (47 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for cloudant to start (46 retries left).

Failed twice.  Any ideas on what can be done?

thanks
--rv

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflw. You need to be more specific. What you are tryig to do? What you expect? What you have tried?

Comment: Hi - while installing IBM Cloud Private 2.1 CE, this step failed twice. Saw references that it used to fail with Beta 2 but the timeout was increased.  Now it is set to 50 retries.  Still it failed.

Comment: Installed the datastore as suggested - still no change

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to check you are sizing the VMs accordingly:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

and following the stated install steps:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/install_containers_CE.html

You can pull the cloudant image before ICP installation, this can workaround the cloudant retrying failed issue.

Comment: I changed the disk size to be 160G. How can I pull the Cloudant image before ICP installation?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Lack of resources, maybe?**

Debug the pod to learn more: [Debugging pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#debugging-pods)

During the `TASK [addon : Waiting for cloudant to start]` phase, the system is checking to make sure that for the pod to see if the desired amount equals the current amount.

If it fails, it usually means they don't match...in other words, your pod did not start.